# Creating images with nice tables

Tags: python

I have some data that I would like to represent as a table. Is there a python library that will allow easy generation of an image with a nice looking table in it?
I know that matplotlib does not have this feature, but maybe some other library has...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

Also a python wrapper for it: [pygooglechart](http://pygooglechart.slowchop.com/)

Comment: Python wrapper does not have table. (Though it exists in Google's API)